# Trying to fix my contact form

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have been trying to figure out on what is missing in my codes. Basically whenever i click the submit button to send the data in the contact form, it basically returns me to the home page and displays "page not found" in the tab.

Here is my code

```
<?php 
$error=false;
$sent=false;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $error = true;
} else {

 $to = "noel@digitalspin.ph";

 $name = trim($_POST['name']);
 $email = trim($_POST['email']);
 $message = trim($_POST['message']);


 $messages ="\r\n Name: $name \r\n Email: $email \r\n Message: $message";
 $headers = "From:" . $name;
 $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

 if($mailsent){
     $sent= true;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Here is my Markup codes

```
<div class="col10">
<div class="contact_form">
<h2>Inquiries/Comments/Suggestions</h2>
<form id="register-form" action="" method="post">

    <?php if($error == true) { ?>
    <p class="error"> There are some misisng fields.</p>
    <?php } if($sent == true) { ?>
    <p class="sent">Thank you for sending your message</p><?php } ?>

    <div class="contact-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">

    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">

    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

    <label>Where did you learn about us?</label>

    <select>
        <option>Word of Mouth</option>
        <option>Billboards</option>
        <option>Roadshows</option>
        <option>Sales agents</option>
        <option>TV ads</option>
        <option>Booths/Exhibits</option>
        <option>Print Ads</option>
        <option>Internet</option>
        <option>Direct Mail</option>
        <option>Flyer</option>
        <option>Referral</option>
        <option>Others</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit">


</form>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: try to give filename in action=""

Comment: You don't need blank action attribute

Comment: Please define subject . I think you missed $subject value

Comment: @Kalpit what do you mean by give "filename in action?"

Answer (score 1):

Write the path in `action` attribute which is responsible to execute the request, instead of leaving it empty. Leaving `action` attribute empty will consider the base path (usually home page) as submission path.

```
<form id="register-form" action="./contact.php" method="post">
```

(Assuming `./contact.php` is the responsible (and relative) path to execute the form submission request.)

Answer (score 0):

try to make your

```
 <from method="POST" action="contact.php">
```

instead

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
```

or else remove **action=""**

Comment: Tried your solution still the same result T_T

Comment: yes sir. my php codes are placed in the same file(contact-page.php)

Comment: it's working fine in my system and assign $subject="Thank you";

Comment: really? I can't think of anything else. I'm pretty sure everything is correct. It still redirects me to the home page

Answer (score 0):

You must specify an action in your form like:

```
<form id="register-form" action="your_file.php" method="post">
```

after that your script will be executed, so then you can make an output like "Email sended" or  redirect to a new page or so.

Comment: What if my PHP codes are also placed in the same page(contact-page.php)

Comment: hmmm when you let action empty then it should redirect to the same page, it should also work when you write your contact-page.php in it or this action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"

when this doesnt work, do you have a redirct in a .htaccess file or in your vhosts?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
<?php 
$error=false;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $error = true;
} else {

 $name = trim($_POST['name']);
 $email = trim($_POST['email']);
 $message = trim($_POST['message']);
 $to = "noel@digitalspin.ph";

 $headers=array(
        'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n",
        'From: '.$to,
        'Content-Type:text/html',
        'Reply-To: noel@digitalspin.ph'
    );
 $subject = "your subject";

 $messages ="\r\n Name: $name \r\n Email: $email \r\n Message: $message";

 if (!mail($email,$subject,$messages,implode("\r\n",$headers))) {
            mail($to, 'Error sending', 'The following order was not sent:&nbsp;');

        }


}
}
?>


<div class="col10">
<div class="contact_form">
<h2>Inquiries/Comments/Suggestions</h2>
<form id="register-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

    <?php if($error == true) { ?>
    <p class="error"> There are some misisng fields.</p>
    <?php } if($sent == true) { ?>
    <p class="sent">Thank you for sending your message</p><?php } ?>

    <div class="contact-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">

    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">

    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

    <label>Where did you learn about us?</label>

    <select>
        <option>Word of Mouth</option>
        <option>Billboards</option>
        <option>Roadshows</option>
        <option>Sales agents</option>
        <option>TV ads</option>
        <option>Booths/Exhibits</option>
        <option>Print Ads</option>
        <option>Internet</option>
        <option>Direct Mail</option>
        <option>Flyer</option>
        <option>Referral</option>
        <option>Others</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit">


</form>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` in action.

```
<form id="register-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: same result. It also redirects me to the home page and display a "Page not found" in the tab of my browser

Comment: So check your code again.I think your code contain header function in your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
your problem is the name of the below html field :

<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">

Instead of giving name="name" try giving it name="your_name"

And the from action = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>"

Try the below code, that will work for you:

<div class="col10">
<div class="contact_form">
<h2>Inquiries/Comments/Suggestions</h2>
<form id="register-form" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">

    <?php if($error == true) { ?>
    <p class="error"> There are some misisng fields.</p>
    <?php } if($sent == true) { ?>
    <p class="sent">Thank you for sending your message</p><?php } ?>

    <div class="contact-form">
    <input type="text" name="your_name" placeholder="Name">

    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">

    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

    <label>Where did you learn about us?</label>

    <select>
        <option>Word of Mouth</option>
        <option>Billboards</option>
        <option>Roadshows</option>
        <option>Sales agents</option>
        <option>TV ads</option>
        <option>Booths/Exhibits</option>
        <option>Print Ads</option>
        <option>Internet</option>
        <option>Direct Mail</option>
        <option>Flyer</option>
        <option>Referral</option>
        <option>Others</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit">


</form>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```